# Is the /eə/ sound related to the /ə/ sound in British English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

Lately I'm into improving my English (UK) pronunciation. I'm using the IPA chart for such purpose.

I was wondering if there's any relationship between the ə sound and the several diphthongs that involves the "schwa" symbols, in the pronunciation (for example eə)

I mean is there some similarity to take into account?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "if there's any relationship between": the same symbol is used because they are effectively identical sounds. (They might not be precisely identical, but they're close enough _for the purposes of English_).

Comment: What I mean is the following: if I listen the vowels I mentioned https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/phonemic-chart to me they sound different the part that is supposed to be a schwa, so what I was trying to understand is how the diphthong are supposed to be pronounced, in my head I thought the pronunciation is a kind of "continuity" between the single sounds mentioned in the diphthongs.

Comment: In that site, I hear the isolated schwa cut a little shorter, but otherwise the same as the last element in the diphthongs.

Comment: [Related.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336582/is-there-a-difference-between-da%CA%8An-and-d%CA%8C%CA%8An)

Comment: Diphthongs aren't always pronounced exactly the same way by all speakers, and the pronunciation of some diphthongs in British English has changed since the symbols were assigned, so if people don't pronounce the last piece of the diphthong exactly like a schwa, it's not something you should worry about.

Comment: You are going for a totally neutral vowel, with all formants equally spaced. Start by making pronouncing it with a liquid **r** (like American do), then relax your tongue root so that the third formant is no longer depressed.

Comment: The schwa is the weak form of every other vowel, so yes - there is a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

The compound phonemes incorporating schwa (such as those in: near goat mature cure) do not in any way reproduce the schwa short vowel sound, although you might think they suggest it.  They are just compound phonemes.  No need to read anything into them.

http://teflpedia.com/Weak_form

Answer (score 1):

The "similarity" is not coincidental; the vowel found in words like "care" is often transcribed as /eə/ because, historically, many people pronounced it like the sound [e] followed by the sound [ə], squished into one syllable. (The non-syllabic part was the [ə]; a more explicit transcription would be /eə̯/.) However, in modern Southern British speech, words like "care" are often pronounced with a long monophthong rather than a centering diphthong due to the phenomenon of "smoothing", so it may be better for you to aim for /ɛː/; at any rate, you should be aware of the existence of this pronunciation.

Here is a blog post about it by Geoff Lindsey: [Smoothing, then and now](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/smoothing-then-and-now/)

Answer (score 0):

A schwa is a very lax, muddy short vowel sound, as in the first syllable of "muddy."

Many vowel combinations make that sound.  It's not about the letters; it's about the sound.

I think the reason why you see so many vowel combinations that result in the sound is because the English language has so many words from so many other languages.

Comment: You should see if you can find any references to back this up. Also, "muddy" [is not pronounced with a schwa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muddy).

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schwa   *A*meric*a* and M*u*ddy are the same sound.

Comment: @Jennifer: in ***some*** dialects of ***American*** English, they are. And maybe some varieties of other Englishes as well. For the rest of us, they're not.

Comment: @JenniferMelekOzgur, schwa is by definition unstressed. The vowel in "muddy" is stressed. The vowels you are referring to in "America" and "muddy" are transcribed differently in IPA. Your answer is not accurate and also doesn't answer the user's question.

Answer (score 0):

The schwa sound is for the unpronounceable (r) in british accent as well so there is a relation between using either the schwa sound or the diphthongs that involves the schwa, and the (r) sound. For example all words that are transcripted using schwa/diphongs with it, include the (r) sound like beer, bear,near,etc 
So i think the only relation between them is the (r) sound